# Error trying to get local images to html (added esModule as false)

Tags: javascript

I get this error **GET [http://10.0.10.14:8000/[object%20Module]](http://10.0.10.14:8000/%5Bobject%20Module%5D) 404 (Not Found)**

html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <img id="popup-sad-icon" src="./images/ErrorPopups_EmojiSad02-ce88eb9a.png" width="40" height="40">
</div>
```

webpack.config.js

```
{
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
    use: [
        {
         loader: 'url-loader',
         options: {
           esModule: false,
          },
        },
    ],
},
```

Thank you